# How to calculate third point of a triangle from two points, angle and edge length?

Tags: geometry, 2d

Using Java, how can I  calculate a third point in triangle if there are known two points, angle between edges and length of an edge?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gENVB6tjq_M

Comment: also.. can you be more precise in which things you know ? i.e. let say the triangle is composed from points A, B,C and the known coords are of points A, B. Which edge's length is know AC,AB etc?

Comment: Adding "Using java" to a question does not make this a programming question. Show us the specific code where you are having problems - [ask]. Without some code, this is a question of mathematics IMO.

Comment: - Points are in 3D. 
- I thought if there is some kind of Java library, that solves that, thats why it si related to Java.
- the known angle lies between the known edges (first one is defined by two points, second one is defined by length and angle between)

Comment: @Jack I'm not sure why you are so upset about my question. I only asked if somebody knows a Java geometry library, that could do the hard work for me. Or if somebody has a implementation of this problem, that i could use.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple : use the [law of Sines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines)

You have two known angles and a known edge.  The unknown angle is presumably opposite the known edge.  Using the property that the internal angles of a triangle always sum to 180 degrees, you can calculate the unknown angle.  Then, sine(angle)/known edge = sine(known angle)/unknown edge.  Solve for both unknown edges and then solve for your point.

Answer (score 1):

You use [triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation).